# Rotating a Circle Curve node using Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am making a logo with an outline, using geometry nodes.
The outline should be flat parallel with the rest of the logo, but is twisted 45 degrees instead 
[image]

Now i am trying to fix this by somehow rotating the "Curve Circle" node but can't find anything that does this.
My current setup is simple like this 
[image]

Does someone know how to do this? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Quadrilateral curve primitive.

[image]

Comment: Omg...this is humiliating 

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Only for completion...

Since you can't create a very usable mesh with the combination `Quadrilateral` and `Curve to Mesh` in this case, you can also use the following setup (assuming it's a cubic shape):

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>